# How can one add a filter across all HttpSecurity Configurers?

Tags: java, spring-security

As a solutions architect, I want to add a filter to all spring security filter chains in the current application context, regardless of how or where they are declared, so that this filter cannot be missed by a developer who forgot to add it.

Suppose that different developers are adding in some custom security to address different logical concerns specific to their filter.  There can be 1 or more WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters

```
public class DeveloperWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .mvcMatcher("/forgottenFilter/**")
                //.addFilter(reallyImportantFilter)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("developerDefinedCriteria");
    }
}
```

I myself could declare a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that adds a filter to the HttpSecurity, but this is treated as an individual catch-all filter chain.

```
public class FrameworkWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    Filter reallyImportantFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilter(reallyImportantFilter);
    }
}
```

In effect, I have not added my filter to the developer's chain, but rather created an entirely separate chain that interferes with the mapping of other filter chains.

```
DefaultSecurityFilterChain INFO: Creating filter chain: any request, [... ReallyImportantFilter@77ce8bc5 ...]

DefaultSecurityFilterChain INFO: Creating filter chain: Mvc [pattern='/forgottenFilter/**'] [...]
```

Is there an out of the box way to configure such a filter?  If not, what patterns can be applied to avoid a filter from being forgotten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A feature of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` came to mind. The [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) states:

> Will automatically apply the result of looking up AbstractHttpConfigurer from SpringFactoriesLoader to allow developers to extend the defaults. To do this, you must create a class that extends AbstractHttpConfigurer and then create a file in the classpath at "META-INF/spring.factories" that looks something like:
>
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer = sample.MyClassThatExtendsAbstractHttpConfigurer

For example, in your case, you can create your own implementation of `AbstractHttpConfigurer` where you add the very important filter:

```
package sample;
// ...
public class CustomSecurityConfigurer<H extends HttpSecurityBuilder<H>>
    extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<CustomSecurityConfigurer<H>, H> {

    @Override
    public void init(H http) { }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(H http) {
        // add your own filter... for example:
        http.addFilterAfter(new ImportantFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);
    }
}
```

... and add this line to the spring.factories in the META-INF folder:

```
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer=sample.CustomSecurityConfigurer
```

In `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, this configurer is added to the "list" of configurers (think `CsrfConfigurer`, `LogoutConfigurer`, ...) that will build the `HttpSecurity`, and ultimately the corresponding filter chain.

If you have multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s, each one will apply this configurer, so you'll end up configuring every filter chain that's created from `HttpSecurity`.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I ended up getting this to work.  I did have to do
`ApplicationContext context = http.getSharedObject(ApplicationContext.class);`
to get something from the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic filter and register it in the servlet context. Here is a sample code for your reference:

```
public class ReallyImportantFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReallyImportantFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            LOGGER.error("Encountered unhandled exception.", t);

            final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
```

Register this filter and assign appropriate order precedence.

```
<bean id="reallyImportantFilterRegistration" class="org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean">
    <property name="filter">
        <bean class="com.test.web.errorhandling.ReallyImportantFilter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="order">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.core.Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: OP wrote: *add a filter to all spring security filter chains* . Your solution is not adding a filter to Spring Security's filter chain, it is adding a filter to servlet's filter chain. Moreover, you didn't change the order for Spring Security's filter chain, hence your filter is applied after all filters in Spring Security's filter chain.